# Passportjs working on localhost but not server

Tags: node.js

Passportjs is authenticating and creating sessions on my localhost but as soon I switch to server it stops working immediately.

I've tried seeing if cookies were being sent and they were not. Session was not created in passportjs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.